# Wordpress: Add Media button on the Add New Post page is not working

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm using WordPress.
The `Add Media` button in the "Add New Post" page did not work:

[image]

Comment: Try to deactivate all plugins..or rename plugin folder and check..

Comment: Please explain this @ i can  Help you

Comment: brother post option i click ad a new post but i include image but add media option not working

Comment: I removed all the crap that wasn't a question at all. Please re-write this to be a proper question.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem recently and it seemed to be a conflict between the Yoast plugin and the theme (Applique).

Answer (score -1):

ok please Remove your plugin one by one  or please  send me a list of plugin or screenshot . If you using any Map plugin or so remove first these. check one by one this will be work  .

Comment: i remove all its working but some plug in i up date i see not working bro

Comment: you mean @ after removing plugin media upload button is working @

Comment: can you inspect and see are there any errrors in console in inspector